# Layout can't be resolved in LayoutInflator in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I used RecyclerView and in The adapter, I used this code

```
View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recy);
```

I have created item_recy layout file but it is showing the error like this

> Cannot resolve symbol 'item _recy'

Please see the pic it a problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6U0i.png)

my adapter cods Please see it

```
package payapay.bornehofficial.myrecyclerview;


import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class AdapterRecy extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecy.ViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recy, parent, false);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

I import R file in project but not solved Please see PIC

```
import payapay.bornehofficial.myrecyclerview.R;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HvQR.png)

Comment: It might have happened due to wrong reference of R.java in that Adapter class. Check that the R is from your project, not from any dependency.

Comment: Reference is right (ctrl+click referral to file  )

Comment: try `View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recy, parent, false);`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue via following steps

1. Close your project
2. Locate your project in file explorer
3. Find `.gradle` and `.idea` folders
4. Delete them
5. Open your project in Android Studio again.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in onCreateViewHolder method in recyclerview Adapter class

> ```
>     View view = LayoutInflater
>             .from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_account_list, parent, false);
> ```

Comment: @atlicode send your adapter class code with import files

Comment: i send please check

Comment: i check your code , i think R file not import, please import R file . in my case `import com.example.android_code.R;`   add this line in your code `import 'your package name'.R`

Comment: I import R file in project but not solved Please see PIC

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your `R` class. The `R.java` is the auto-generated class by buid system and contains all the reference in addressable format. It includes the references for `drawable`, 'layouts' etc. You just need to rebuild your project or you can try clean build. once build finishes, it will be resolved automatically.
There is one more issue in your code, You should inflate `Layout` in `ViewGroup Parent`. See the method signatures here,

> view inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root)
>
> Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource.

Read More about the  [`LayoutInflator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater)

Comment: I'm pretty sure, It's `R.java` issue, do one thing, remove that `R.layout.item_recy` and add it again, but this time use `Tab` hint and check your layout is visible in autocomplete or not?

Comment: post the complete `StackTrace` please.